# javascript regex -- only produces last letter in (.)+ group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a string by regex and getting an unexpected result:

```
var str = 'name == abcd';
var pattern = /([^!=>< ]+)\s*([!=><]+)\s*(.)+/i;

pattern.exec(str);
```

the result of the example is : `[ "name == abcd", "name", "==", **"d"** ]`

why **`"d"`** and not **`"abcd"`**?

Comment: Did you mean `([^!=>< ]+)\s*([!=><]+)\s*(.+)`?

Comment: If you want `abcd`, why not: `str.split('==').pop();`? It doesn't answer your question, but your regex is hideously complex for such a simple thing.

Comment: You are probably also missing `$` at the end of pattern

Comment: @VladL The anchors (`^` and `$`) are not strictly necessary

Comment: @NullUserException how should regex know until there to match? \s*(.+) will match one symbol after white space(s). \s*(.+)$ will match all symbols from white space to the end of the string.

Comment: @VladL Sure. But in this case, it makes no difference whether you have the `$` or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capturing group `(.)` only captures one character. The construct `(.)+` means "one or more capturing groups, each containing one character". It returns only "d" because that is the last iteration of the capturing group encountered.

If you move the repetition inside the capturing group, `(.+)`, you will then have asked for "a capturing group containing one or more characters". This is probably what you want.

```
var pattern = /([^!=>< ]+)\s*([!=><]+)\s*(.+)/i;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a problem with /(\w|\%|\[or\])+/gi only returning the last char, and your respons made me realize that /((\w|\%|\[or\])+)/ could solve that.
Figured it could help someone else to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

Move the last `+` into the parenthesis:

```
var pattern = /([^!=>< ]+)\s*([!=><]+)\s*(.+)/i;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because last pair of parentheses captures only last match. 
Move + into parentheses:
`/([^!=>< ]+)\s*([!=><]+)\s*(.+)/i;`

Comment: @Null: ...even *I* don't know what *that* comment means... O.o

Comment: @NullUserException: +1000 for `vi`

Comment: @DavidThomas The answer originally read "... parentheses captures only **first** match," when it should really say "... captures only [the] **last** match," and that command performs a search and replace. I was actually thinking [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) instead of vi

Comment: @NullUserException - yes, different regex engines behave differently in this case - I fixed the answer when I realized my mistake. JS captures the last match.

Comment: @Cozzamara Which regex engine captures the first match? AFAIK all PCRE engines capture the last match.

Comment: @Null: I...think it was explained to me over on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Mindez/status/291326516846030848). But...I think this is the reason that Vi, or perhaps sed, are considered obscure tools. That, or I'm having a massive attack of stupid, right now...(yes, and we all know which is the more likely *cough* latter *cough*)

Comment: @NullUserException - you're right - they all capture the last occurrence - not the first, PCRE or not, including vi and sed - not sure where that came from - I must have dealt with too many of these engines.