# Regexp: symbols missing in group

Tags: python, regex

I seen this thread:
[javascript regex -- only produces last letter in (.)+ group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348674/javascript-regex-only-produces-last-letter-in-group)

The solution, offered there don't help in my case; what I tried:

```
^{[^d]*([\d\-]+),([\d\-]+)[^d]*{?(\d+)}?[^}]+}$
```

[Online demo at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lM5hD1/2)

We need parse strings `{left/(-1,0)/$\upsilon_{11}$}` and `{left/(1,0)/$\upsilon_{1}$}` as

```
[(-1,0,11),(1,0,1)].
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
[(1,0,1),(1,0,1)].
```

How to change it?

Comment: Martijn Pieters, thank you for changing the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *include* `-` in the negative character class at the start:

```
^{[^d-]*([\d\-]+),([\d-]+)[^d]*{?(\d+)}?[^}]+}$
```

Making it *non-greedy* will help too:

```
^{[^d-]*?([\d\-]+),([\d-]+)[^d]*?{?(\d+)}?[^}]+}$
```

Demo at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bR0lI8/4).

Python session:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^{[^d-]*?([\d\-]+),([\d-]+)[^d]*?{?(\d+)}?[^}]+}$', re.M)
>>> pattern.search('{left/(-1,0)/$\upsilon_{11}$}').groups()
('-1', '0', '11')
>>> pattern.search('{left/(1,0)/$\upsilon_{1}$}').groups()
('1', '0', '1')
```

Comment: I slightly mistook at original regexp, but with your help I get that I want to get: http://regex101.com/r/bR0lI8/3 Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for nice troubleshooting and including sample code :)